# Restcomm on Tomcat Click2CallAsync User Registration

Tags: tomcat, servlets, restcomm, mobicents

I managed to start Restcomm on Tomcat and can see what supposed to be there at both 127.0.0.1:8080 and 127.0.0.1:8080/Click2CallAsync. At Click2CallAsync page, it asks me to register at least two users but I don't seem to be able to do that. I follow the steps exactly as it is told at [Restcomm SIP Servlets User Guide](http://documentation.telestax.com/core/sip_servlets/SIP_Servlets_Server_User_Guide.html#_getting_started_with_mss_tomcat_as7)
but I still can't see my users. I also tried two additional softphones other than Linphone but still the same. What am I supposed to do, how do I establish a SIP Servlet connection and make calls?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reloading the page just in case ? This app has not been updated in a while. If that still doesn't work can you share DEBUG logs ?

Comment: Yes, I refreshed the page several times, didn't work. About the logs, would it it be too awkward if I said I'm not exactly sure about how to do that? As I mentioned earlier I've been assigned to research SIP-Servlets as an Intern and I am still in the process of learning all these stuff.

Comment: No worries, look in the logs folder of tomcat and send the content of the server log in there.

Comment: Here, the link to the whole folder in case you need to check the other files too.Also, although the users didn't appear on the page, I was able to initiate a call between these two users successfully. And when a terminated the service the call was not able to initiate, naturally.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3cdFn3cPCneUExkdGtuT2VBYTg/view

Comment: I also tried the "-wildfly-10.0.0.Final" version, the result is the same.

Comment: Did you find anything?